# How to Forward a DNS subdomain in my DNS server to be fulfilled by Azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns, forwarding

I have a set of DNS servers in my company that host many web sites. we are experimenting with hosting some of them in Azure. I would like to create a sub domain like  xxx.myazure.mycompany.com where the DNS servers can forward the sub domain myazure zones to azure DNS, to be specific I would like to have my servers resolve all mycompany.com requests and have azure dns resolve all myazue.mycompany.com queries. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, that is not uncommon setup

Answer (score 0):

The following article describes how to delegate a sub-domain. In this example both zones are hosted by Azure DNS, but you should be able to use the corresponding workflow with the provider hosting your parent zone to achieve what you are looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns#delegate-sub-domains-in-azure-dns